# SQL XML Bulk Loader - Error connecting

Tags: sql, xml

I'm using the sqlxmlbulkloadlib to perform an xml bulk load.  When integrated security=SSPI, the process completes fine inside a workflow hosted on my local machine in a wcf service.  However, when that workflow is hosted on our server and kicked off from a service reference on an aspx page, the bulkloader produces an error connecting to the data source.  I have tried using sql server authentication instead, but that fails even on my local machine with the same error connecting to data source.

My connection string looks like:
"provider=SQLOLEDB;data source=Myserver;database=Mydb;User ID=Myuser;Password=Mypassword"

Comment: What version of SQL? How is your environment structured (App on Server1, Db on Server2, Bulk load file on Server3)? What type of authentication is you application using (Windows, Forms etc)? Is you wcf service hosted in IIS or run as a windows service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after creating the sql account for the bulkloader, the policy required that I change the password.  Didn't catch that till I tried logging in with the account in management studio.

I am curious, though, what I would have to do differently for integrated security to work from the production server.

Comment: (In case it isn't clear, having logged in and changed the password in sql management studio, the bulk loader is able to successfully connect.)